# Where in Wordpress DB are stored wp_cron tasks?

Tags: wordpress, cron

I was looking in wp_options table but there is nothing like that eventhough I have set my cron tasks like:

```
add_action('init', function() {
    if ( !wp_next_scheduled('my_awesome_cron_hook') ) {
        wp_schedule_event(time(), 'hourly', 'my_awesome_cron_hook');
    }
});
```

Or is it stored in some txt file in wordpress?

Answer (score 62, accepted):

It's stored in the database inside `wp_options` under the `option_name` `cron`.

You can get the array with: `_get_cron_array()` or `get_option('cron')`.

See: http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/trunk/wp-includes/cron.php

Comment: Ahh I see it now. It's stored as an array in wp_options table and option_name is cron.

Comment: Don't use `_get_cron_array()`. This function’s access is marked private. This means it is not intended for use by plugin or theme developers, only in other core functions. It is listed here for completeness.